# copy_from_user function prints junk values

Tags: c, linux, sockets, kernel

I am trying to print the content of the user space buffer in the kernel space, but I am getting some junk characters and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE6(sendto, int, fd, void __user *, buff, size_t, len,
    unsigned, flags, struct sockaddr __user *, addr,
    int, addr_len) {

 char *messageRead = kmalloc(len,GFP_KERNEL);
 unsigned long bytesNotCopied = copy_from_user(messageRead,(char*)buff,len);
 printk("The messageRead Read is %s \n",messageRead);

.....
.....

}
```

The bytesNotCopied returns 0, so I was able to confirm that the content was copied. but when I tried to print the messageRead value, it is returning me some junk values.

Comment: The function won't compile, as the type for `buff` is missing. Also there is misplaced comma between `size_t` and `len`.

Comment: And how is this related to sockets?

Comment: alk, this is the format which is being followed in the kernel space.

Comment: I suspect it should read: `int printChar(void __user * buff, size_t len)`.

Comment: alk, thanks for helping me out, let me modify the code and post it again and I am trying to print the content in socket.c file

Comment: how come you want to do things by adding a new syscall? it's very often the last option.

Comment: May be the buff passed is not initialized? Otherwise the function seems fine.

Comment: hmm, Correct me if i am wrong, what I am trying to do is, I am trying to print  payload content (tcp packets) which is coming from the user space in the above function, I also did the following, I inserted similar code inside the sendmsg system call function, to make sure that I cover all the base, but still I am seeing only junk characters, my assumption is that, all the payload data from the user space should either be sent through send(this one internally redirects to sendto) or sendmsg system call and I should be seeing the payload content. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

A return value of 0 indicates a successful copy. 
Why do you want to print the buffer as string i.e using %s in printk(). Is buff a character string in the user process?. If not try dumping this way

```
for(i=0; i<len; i++) /*make sure you declare i */
{
    printk("%x ",messageRead[i]);
}
```

Comment: yes, mostly the buff is a char string in the user space, I was hoping to see some strings getting printed,(for example http get request, post ...), but I was not seeing any info like that, also as suggested let me try printing it in hex format.